# Why am I getting a (401) Unauthorized Error in Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, unauthorized

Ive been playing around with the Google Calendar API and am getting stuck on something.  When i call this below to **delete a calendar event** it works fine on the first pass and usually the second.  However, around the 2nd or 3rd time I call this method I get a **(401) Unauthorized error**.  It uses the same credentials every time.  If I get the exception, I can **reset the credentials** in the catch and it works fine.  I would prefer not to have to do this.  Any ideas?

```
        CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("mycompany-myapp-1");
        myService.setUserCredentials("jo@username.com", "password");


        // set the query for the event
        EventQuery myQuery = new EventQuery(("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jo@username.com/private/full"));
        myQuery.Query = "Cut the grass";
        myQuery.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        myQuery.EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        // find the event
        EventFeed myResultsFeed = null;

        try
        {
            // execute the query to find the event
            myResultsFeed = myService.Query(myQuery);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // this is where i get the unauthorized exception
            // if i reset the credentials here it works fine

            myService.setUserCredentials("jo@username.com", "password"); 
            myResultsFeed = myService.Query(myQuery);
        }

        if (myResultsFeed != null && myResultsFeed.Entries.Count > 0)
        {
            AtomEntry firstMatchEntry = myResultsFeed.Entries[0];
            firstMatchEntry.Delete();
        }
```

Comment: What happends if you use the Feed URI you have? is it authorized in the webbrowser or is restricted?

Answer (score 1):

**[NODE JS]** I know it was 8 years ago but somehow I got into such an error and got this from stack :) I forgot to pass 'auth' object into request. The full schema is:

```js
    interface Params$Resource$Events$Delete extends StandardParameters {
        /**
         * Auth client or API Key for the request
         */
        auth?: string | OAuth2Client | JWT | Compute | UserRefreshClient;
        /**
         * Calendar identifier. To retrieve calendar IDs call the calendarList.list
         * method. If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently
         * logged in user, use the "primary" keyword.
         */
        calendarId?: string;
        /**
         * Event identifier.
         */
        eventId?: string;
        /**
         * Deprecated. Please use sendUpdates instead.  Whether to send
         * notifications about the deletion of the event. Note that some emails
         * might still be sent even if you set the value to false. The default is
         * false.
         */
        sendNotifications?: boolean;
        /**
         * Guests who should receive notifications about the deletion of the event.
         */
        sendUpdates?: string;
    }
```

Maybe in your case the problem is with refresh/access token... I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that more information is needed. The best way is to use [fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by creating a webbrowser control that navigates to the api on load and just never show it to the user. Only solution I have found that 100% fixes the issue.